# Using rssh to chroot causes rsync (code 12) error

Tags: linux, ssh, backup, rsync, chroot

I'm configuring my home NAS to periodically pull down backups from another server.

On the server is a dummy-user using the rssh shell configured to only allow rsync access. I'd like to also chroot the user into the backup directory so that they do not have access to the rest of the system.

When the `chrootpath` key is commented out, the following command successfully lists the root directory contents:

`rsync --list-only server:/`

When the `chrootpath` variable is set, to `/my/backup/path` or any directory *including* `/`, the same command fails with:

```
rsync: connection unexpectedly closed (0 bytes received so far) [Receiver]
rsync error: error in rsync protocol data stream (code 12) at io.c(601) [Receiver=3.0.7]
```

As does `rsync --list-only server:/my/backup/path/`.

I'm not sure where I'm going wrong. Everything works great if I'm not enforcing chroot. I also disabled rssh's chrootpath and set `ChrootDirectory` in a Match User clause in my sshd_config. I got the same (code 12) results from rsync.

Comment: Do you have rsync under `/my/backup/path`?

Comment: Yes. I had it linked before, but I just tested by copying the binary from /usr/bin and giving it 777 permissions. Same result.

Comment: ...and the depended libraries?

Comment: The libraries as reported by `ldd`? No. That seems like a messy solution. Is there a better way to accomplish the goal of preventing the NAS user from accessing the rest of the server?

Comment: use rsync natively, it has builtin daemon support. it would be also faster than going through ssh. btw. this is the recommended way.